# Proof or reference that $X \to X^I$ is a Hurewicz cofibration

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I would like to know a proof that, given $X$ a topological space, the map $X \to X^I$, $x \mapsto \textrm{const}_x$ is a Hurewicz cofibration (I know how to prove that it is in fact a homotopy equivalence).

I can believe that the image is closed (though a proof or reference would be also nice) and I am allowed to use the retraction argument, but I'm unable to give a reasonable map.

Comment: Why do you believe that this map is a cofibration?

Comment: There is a comment on this map at the end of Strom's famous "homotopy category" paper: https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/Strom.pdf He mentions that the map is a cofibration for nice spaces (CW-complexes/metric spaces), but points to a reference for a counterexample for the general case.

Comment: @Tyrone Because $X^I$ is a path object in the model category homotopy equivalences of Top.  Namely, I want to factorize the diagonal map of $X$ passing through $X^I$, and I want such a map to be acyclic cofibration.