# When is the inclusion of the constant paths $X\hookrightarrow X^I$ a cofibration?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a space and $X^I$ the space of continuous maps $I=[0,1]\rightarrow X$ in the compact-open topology. There is a map $c:X\rightarrow X^I$, $x\mapsto c_x$, which sends a point $x\in X$ to the constant path at $x$. This map is an embedding since it has a left inverse. Its image is closed if $X$ has enough open sets (in particular if $X$ is Hausdorff).

> When is the map $c:X\rightarrow X^I$ a cofibration?

Comment: See my comment here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3095261/proof-or-reference-that-x-to-xi-is-a-hurewicz-cofibration#comment6381677_3095261

Comment: @JustinYoung so it seems like requiring local equiconnectedness is sufficient. Thanks, Justin, that answers my question. If you post an answer I will accept.